# How to manipulate "if condition" in ORACLE SQL PROCEDURE?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am using ORACLE 10g & PHP codeigniter for my application.
I have a procedure defined like this:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
        insertMovie (id IN NUMBER, title IN VARCHAR2, 
            sdate IN DATE, edate IN DATE,
                        image IN VARCHAR2, add_date IN DATE,
            message OUT NUMBER) 
    AS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_sdate, movie_edate, movie_image, movie_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, 'title', to_date('sdate', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('edate', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'movie_image', to_date('add_date', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
            message:= 1;
        END;
/
```

Now, I want a if condition to return either 1 or 0. If insert will be successful, message will be 1. If insert fails. message will be 0.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `EXCEPTION` block to trap any exceptions occured while executing the proc and set message to 0.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
        insertMovie (id IN OUT NUMBER, title IN VARCHAR2, 
            sdate IN DATE, edate IN DATE,
                        image IN VARCHAR2, add_date IN DATE,
            message OUT NUMBER) 
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF ID is NULL THEN
               ID := SOME_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO tbl_movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_sdate, movie_edate, movie_image, movie_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, 'title', to_date('sdate', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('edate', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'movie_image', to_date('add_date', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
            message := 1;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            message := 0;
        END;
/
```

Comment: How can I return the last inserted movie_id if the insert is successful?

Comment: you only are passing the id into the proc. So, you can check if message is 1 then use the id you passed into the procedure.

Comment: Sorry, actually I meant it like this. Here I am explicitly passing the ID, so I can use it. What if I would have been using sequence.next_val. That time I need to return the id..

Comment: @saswat - Updated the answer. Changed the id param from IN to IN OUT and check if the id is null. If it is null, assign it the from seq.nextval. On calling you can check if message is 1, and read the id fro in out param.